# Запись русских символов в базу данных

Tags: c++, mysql, кодировка, qt5

Записываю имя и фамилию (русскими символами) в БД через программу Qt5, захожу в базу данных и в поле имя и фамилия вижу такое

[image: Вот так выглядит база]

Поля имя и фамилия в кодировке

> cp1251_general_ci

Почему не видит русских символов? Если что, все пишется через локальный сервер (localhost)

***Код***

```
if(db.open())
       {
           // Inserting data


           QSqlQuery qry;

           qry.prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (name, lastname, phonenumber, totalbuy)"
                       "VALUES (:name, :lastname, :phonenumber, :totalbuy)");
           qry.bindValue(":name", name);
           qry.bindValue(":lastname", lastname);
           qry.bindValue(":phonenumber", phonenumber);
           qry.bindValue(":totalbuy", totalbuy);


           if(qry.exec())
           {
               QMessageBox::information(this, "Успешно", "Данные успешно записаны");
           }else{
               QMessageBox::warning(this, "Ошибка", "Данные не записаны");
           }
           db.close();
       }
```

Comment: QtCreator по умолчанию использует UTF-8, рекомендую бд тоже сохранять в этой же кодировке

Comment: Не работает ни UTF-8, ни CP1251

Comment: В вашем примере никак не удостоверяется, что кодировка lastname и прочих вставляемых полей соответствует той, которую ожидает база.

Comment: @user7860670 как тогда правильно указать?

Comment: Если кодировка строк не соответствует, то ее надо конвертировать в нужную. В Qt по идее есть встроенные средства для этого. Или можно взять библиотеки icu или iconv.